# QTP: Exit Test from nested function

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

My test has multiple nested functions. Any function can be called from any other function. In a step, I need to read error message om webpage and retry, ignore or abort:

```
Function DataProcess_Errors (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
If Mybrowser1.WebTable("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=Table2","name:=WebTable","visible:=True").WebElement("html tag:=DIV", "html id:=divErrorMsg").Exist(1) Then
If Len(Mybrowser1.WebTable("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=Table2","name:=WebTable","visible:=True").WebElement("html tag:=DIV", "html id:=divErrorMsg").GetROProperty("innertext"))>0 Then
BtnClicked = msgbox (Mybrowser1.WebTable("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=Table2","name:=WebTable","visible:=True").WebElement("html tag:=DIV", "html id:=divErrorMsg").GetROProperty("innertext"), 18, "Error occured")
    If BtnClicked = 3 Then 'if clicked "Abort" 
        ExitRun
    ElseIf BtnClicked = 4 Then 'if clicked "Retry"
        Call DataProcess_Errors (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4) 'call this function
    ElseIf BtnClicked = 5 Then 'if clicked "Ignore"
        Exit Function 'continue to next step
    End If    
ElseIf Mybrowser1.WebElement("html tag:=DIV", "html id:=divInfo").Exist(1) Then
print Mybrowser1.WebTable("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=Table2","name:=WebTable","visible:=True").WebElement("html tag:=DIV", "html id:=divInfo").GetROProperty("innertext") 
End If
End If
End Function
```

The problem is, the function does not exit test. I tried `ExitTest`, `ExitRun`, `ExitAction` - none of them exit the test but continue to next step.
Tried next:

```
Dim qtAppObj : Set qtAppObj = CreateObject("quicktest.application")
qtAppObj.Test.Stop
```

With this one UFT foes to debugging and just halts - nothing works but 'kill' UFT from Task Manager.

Any advice, any suggestion?

P.S. (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4) should be there, because all functions are called by `GetRef`which should pass those variables to 90% of all functions in the library.

Comment: Sometimes   ExitTest , ExitRun  does  not work  when you  have nested function call. you can  try with exit function instead ExitRun and return a boolean value from your function like this:  If BtnClicked = 3 Then  
          1) DataProcess_Errors = false                                                        
           2)  Exit Function
    End if .         And use  below condition  where you call this function .   if DataProcess_Errors = false then exitTest End if. just give a try whether it works or not.

Comment: Agree, that has to be handled with logic not through QTP keywords. Put a flag like 'Pass/Fail' or 'True/False' And exit function based on that.

Comment: Absolutely. The logic worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and lost at least two hours of lifetime fixing it.

Having `ExitTest`, `ExitAction`, `ExitComponent` not working for me was 
caused by setting `On Error Resume Next` in the sequence before it.
More accurately, it was set to just one function before.

To Illustrate quickly.

```
On Error Resume Next
Check something
For a certain condition: Call ExitRun("TEST")

Public Function ExitRun(str_inExitType)
On Error Goto 0
Select Case UCase(str_inExitType)
Case "TEST" ExitTest
End Function
```

Even having `On Error Goto 0` in the ExitRun Function, it didn't work.

I had to set it back to `On Error Goto 0` in the function where I set it previously to `On Error Resume Next`.

```
On Error Resume Next
Check something
On Error Goto 0
For a certain condition: Call ExitRun("TEST")
```

Very strange, not obvious.